# SQL Query Not Adding New Entries With INSERT IGNORE INTO

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

So I have a script that gets data about 100 items at a time and inserts them into a MySQL database with a command like this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO beer(name, type, alcohol_by_volume, description, image_url) VALUES('Bourbon Barrel Porter', 2, '9.1', '', '')
```

I ran the script once, and it populated the DB with 100 entries. However, I ran the script again with the same SQL syntax, gathering all new data (i.e., no duplicates), but the database is not reflecting any new entries -- it is the same 100 entries I inserted on the first iteration of the script.

I logged the queries, and I can confirm that the queries were making requests with the new data, so it's not a problem in the script not gathering new data.

The name field is a unique field, but no other fields are. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `IGNORE` keyword, errors that occur while executing the `INSERT` statement are treated as warnings instead. For example, without IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing `UNIQUE` index or `PRIMARY KEY` value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With `IGNORE`, the row still is not inserted, but no error is issued.

If there is no primary key, there can't be duplicate key to ignore. you should always set a primary key, so please do that - and if you want to have additional colums that shouldn't be duplicate, set them as "`unique`".

Comment: The table I'm inserting in does have a unique primary key, id, in addition to a unique name field. The primary key field is an integer and it is set to auto increment. My SQL statements don't explicitly insert the primary key, though. So if I don't explicitly insert a primary key with the IGNORE INSERT statement, is it trying to insert keys starting from id 1, thus causing the script not to write anything new? I was under the impression that it would just pick up where it left off if I have a primary key integer if it's auto_increment.